# OneSignal Unsubscribe User with a toggle button

Tags: android, ionic-framework, onesignal

I have successfully implemented push notification for my android app using OneSignal. I have implemented a checkbox in settings to enable user to opt out from receiving notifications.

Didn't figure out how to disable / enable notification. I wente through the documentation and didn't figure out how to disable notification.

Answer (score 3):

Just set subscription to false to opt out from receiving notification.

`OneSignal.setSubscription(false);`

false to opt out and true to opt in.

**UPDATE**

// for Android SDK version 4.x.x

`OneSignal.disablePush(true);`

Answer (score 1):

```
OneSignal.setSubscription(isChecked);
```

**Using switch**

```
public SharedPreferences pref = activity.getSharedPreferences(myPreference, 0); // 0 - for private mode
public SharedPreferences.Editor  editor = pref.edit();


switch_noti.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                OneSignal.setSubscription(isChecked);
                sharePrefEditor.putBoolean("noti", isNotification);
               sharePrefEditor.apply();
            }
        });
```

Store true/false in SharedPreferences

```
   if (sharedPref.getBoolean("noti", true)) {
        switch_noti.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        switch_noti.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Set `isChecked=true` to recive notification else set `isChecked=false` to disable notification

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one

```
if (isChecked) {
   OneSignal.disablePush(false);
} else {
  OneSignal.disablePush(true);
}
```

Visit [the official documentation for more details](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sdk-reference#disablepush-method)